# Is there a standard notation for the Galois group of a polynomial?

Tags: notation, galois-theory

Is there any standard notation for the Galois group of a polynomial $f$? I've been writing $\text{Gal}(f)$ but I've recently realised I probably just made that up. I know that you could denote the splitting field by $L/K$ and write $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ but I was wondering if there was a notation just in terms of $f$, which would be convenient.

Comment: I think $\mathrm{Gal}(f)$ is fine **If the smaller field $K$ is absolutely clear from the context^**. Particularly if we can infer that $K$ is a prime field.

Comment: Yes I agree, I'm referring to the case where the field is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ is standard.